# Nginx Webserver Reverse Proxy Unauthorized Access?

Tags: nginx, webserver, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am having a very strange issue on Nginx web server. I have a virtual host with fully qualified domain name in server block, this virtual host basically does the work of reverse proxying to the service running in another port (8080) of the localhost. The problem now is somebody from unauthorized site is accessing the service. Below is the snippet of my vhost config:

```
server {
        server_name subdomain.test.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }


    listen 80; # managed by Certbot

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    <ssl config from certbot>

}
```

Now as per the above server block, only visitors coming from `subdomain.test.com` is supposed to access service running on :8080. I found that some guy is accessing the same service of :8080 from `fakedomain.other.com`. the one with fakedomain is using cloudflare and is getting response header like given below:

```
HTTP/2 200 OK
date: Mon, 18 Sep 2023 07:05:28 GMT
content-type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
x-route-time: 263
x-run-time: 38
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
access-control-expose-headers: Server, range, X-Run-Time, X-Sid, Content-Length, Location
access-control-allow-headers: x-vsaas-session, x-no-redirect, origin, authorization, accept, range, content-type, x-add-effective, session, x-originator, x-sid
x-sid: 6507f2f9-1eb4-4b1d-9fd4-9598d08f3f1b
cache-control: no-cache
pragma: no-cache
pragma: https://subdomain.test.com/vidfile/tracks-v1a1/mono.m3u8
x-cached: yes
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=zu7bGBYpQlVSTUp%2BzCABW89cFnfosKydBF8wEltOp48%2FcWqA2kUBqOohBM2IWCSZtCY4Jlt4r6A%2F1rLceZ0C%2Fh9%2Fc81M0I32LrpocB7gHPkivyEqae6N003ebzQnp0VdgfLFYUg%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 8087bd9cdbcc9e80-KTM
content-encoding: br
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Here object pragma contains my domain name and uri. I tried searching for possible reasons on how this is happening but without success. Can you please enlighten me on how this is possible? Also possible solution to protect my assets from malicious site accessing it? Thank you for reading this.